# Retrofit swap JSON objects

Tags: android, json, database, retrofit

What is the simplest way to swap two objects places so their new order would be saved in database?
Thank you.

My path is:
https://localapi.io/artists?userId=1

I have a list of JSON objects.

```
[
  {
    "deviceId": "1eb5e6bb-d08b-4f3b-8d71-2b3aab6547c9",
    "name": "MDQ",
    "phone": "7738375513",
    "id": 1,
    "userId": 1
  },
  {
    "deviceId": "2eb5e6bb-d08b-4f3b-8d71-2b3aab6547c9",
    "name": "Prismatix",
    "phone": "2244427841",
    "id": 2,
    "userId": 1
  },
  {
    "deviceId": "3eb5e6bb-d08b-4f3b-8d71-2b3aab6547c9",
    "name": "Anderson Paak",
    "phone": "3246743463",
    "id": 3,
    "userId": 1
  },
  {
    "deviceId": "7eb5e6bb-d08b-4f3b-8d71-2b3aab6547c9",
    "name": "Snarky Puppy",
    "phone": "7738375515",
    "id": 7,
    "userId": 1
  }
]
```

Field "id" is the one that identifies an artist.

Answer (score 0):

**For example if using python**

---

the object is a variable named object

---

use this to swap

```
object[0],object[1]=object[1],object[0]
```

Comment: I'm working in Android studio. I can swap it in my app but also I want to make a permanent changes on backend also.

Comment: You can add the code in back-end where is post route is working